# Template in Mojolicious controller not found

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to serve a template contained in the `__DATA__` section of a controller class, but it doesn't seem to work.

In my main `app.pl` file I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/lib";


push @{app->renderer->classes},   'Zairyo::Controller::Data';
push @{app->preload_namespaces},  'Zairyo::Controller::Data';

get '/:uid'  => [uid => qr/[a-z0-9]{32,32}/i ] => { controller => 'Data', action => 'serve_iframe' };

app->start;
```

and in `Zairyo::Controller::Data`:

```
package Zairyo::Controller::Data;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub serve_iframe ($c) {
    $c->render(template => 'foo');
}

__DATA___

@@ foo.html.ep
what is this
```

which I'd expect to work as per the [documentation](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Renderer#classes) but instead throws an error `Could not render a response...` on the browser and `Template "foo.html.ep" not found` on the log.

I've solved this by doing

```
$c->render(inline => data_section(__PACKAGE__, 'foo.html.ep') );
```

but it seems a bit of a hack.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there something mixed up about your question? You use the same `render` call to say it doesn't work and it does work. What happens if you preload the `Zairyo::Controller::Data` class, since the docs say "Note that for templates to be detected, these classes need to have already been loaded and added before `warmup` is called"

Comment: You may need to add `use lib '.'` to your script if the `Zairyo/Controller/Data.pm` file is in the current directory

Comment: Also I am not sure about the `app->preload_namespaces` call, I could not find any examples of it used. Instead try this: `push @{app->routes->namespaces}, 'Zairyo::Controller';` Note: without the trailing `::Data` since the namespace should be a directory and I assume `Data.pm` is a file inside `Zairyo/Controller/` directory

Comment: @briandfoy yes - sorry, I used the code that worked. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are a few things a bit off in your *Data.pm*:

- There are three underscores after `__DATA` when there should be two and a newline
- The module does not return a true value

Here's what I ended up with:

```
package Zairyo::Controller::Data;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub serve_iframe ($c) {
    $c->render(template => 'foo' );
}

1;

__DATA__

@@ foo.html.ep
what is this
```

In the main script, I load the class before I call `start`. Note that the [docs say](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Renderer#classes):

> Note that for templates to be detected, these classes need to have already been loaded and added before warmup is called

And, `warmup` is called immediately by `start`, and it's `warmup` that cares about `preload_namespaces`. You need to get there even sooner, so `preload_namespaces` does nothing for this particular problem. If you haven't already loaded the module, its `__DATA__` templates will not be detected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/lib";

push @{app->renderer->classes}, map { Mojo::Loader::load_class($_); $_ } 'Zairyo::Controller::Data';

get '/:uid'  => [uid => qr/[a-z0-9]{32,32}/i ] => {
    namespace  => 'Zairyo::Controller',
    controller => 'Data',
    action     => 'serve_iframe'
    };

app->start;
```

I'm not suggesting this particular code, but now I know why you weren't getting what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry for the underscores and lack of true value. I messed it up when cutting out (what I thought were) the non-relevant bits of the controller module (which worked in its non-snipped version). And thank you very much for your answer